# JavaFX is locking the app when after ActionEvent is done

Tags: javafx-2, actionevent

I am building a menu (file, view, help, etc.). For ex. in File you have upload and exit (both working fine). In help I have some topics: ACF, ARIMA, HoltWinter, the idea is when you chose one of these a text to be displayed in a GridPane. The problem is when you chose one, it displays its text, but it also locks the whole app and you can do nothing, except close the app. 
This is a file chooser and it's working just fine:

```
 MenuItem upload = new MenuItem("Upload");
    upload.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);           
        }
    });
```

And here is an event, which is blocking the app:

```
MenuItem acfH = new MenuItem("ACF");
    acfH.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            fr.md.pack.TextClass.acfText.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            fr.md.pack.TextClass.acfText.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutACF);
            grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.acfText,1,10);
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions how to solve the issue?
Thanks in advance.

Here is the whole code:

```
public class MD extends Application {

@Override
public void start(final Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {

    primaryStage.setTitle("Crude oil price prediction");

    primaryStage.getIcons().add(new Image("file:resources/images/DukeWithHelmet.png"));

    final GridPane grid = new GridPane();   
    grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    grid.setHgap(10);
    grid.setVgap(10);
    grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Group root = new Group();
    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500,500, Color.WHITE);


    scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("style.css")
               .toExternalForm());

    primaryStage.setTitle("Crude oil price predicition");


    menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());

    Menu file = new Menu("File2");
    MenuItem upload = new MenuItem("Upload");
    upload.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            FileChooser fileChooser = new FileChooser();
            fileChooser.setTitle("Open Resource File");
            fileChooser.showOpenDialog(primaryStage);           
        }
    });

    MenuItem exit = new MenuItem("Exit");
    exit.setMnemonicParsing(true);
    exit.setAccelerator(new KeyCodeCombination(KeyCode.X,KeyCombination.CONTROL_DOWN));
    exit.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        Platform.exit();
      }
    });

    Menu test = new Menu("Test");

    MenuItem arima = new MenuItem ("ARIMA");
    arima.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      }
    });

    MenuItem acf = new MenuItem ("ACF");
    acf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      }
    });

    MenuItem pacf = new MenuItem ("PACF");
    pacf.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      }
    });


    MenuItem hw = new MenuItem ("HoltWinters");
    hw.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

      }
    });

    Menu help = new Menu("Help");

    MenuItem arimaH = new MenuItem ("ARIMA");

    arimaH.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.arimaText.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.arimaText.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutArima);
          grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.arimaText, 1, 10);

      }
    });




    MenuItem acfH = new MenuItem("ACF");
    acfH.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
        public void handle(ActionEvent event){
            fr.md.pack.TextClass.acfText.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
            fr.md.pack.TextClass.acfText.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutACF);
            grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.acfText,1,10);
        }
    });

    MenuItem pacfH = new MenuItem ("PACF");
    pacfH.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.pacfText.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.pacfText.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutPACF);
          grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.pacfText, 1, 10);
      }
    });

    MenuItem hwH = new MenuItem ("HoltWinters");
    hwH.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.hwText.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.hwText.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutHW);
          grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.hwText, 1, 10);
      }
    });

    Menu about = new Menu("About");

    MenuItem thisS = new MenuItem ("About this software");
    thisS.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.textRef.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.aboutSoft.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutSofttext);
          grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.aboutSoft, 1, 40);
      }
    });

    MenuItem R = new MenuItem ("About R");
    R.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.textRef.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.aboutR.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutRtext);
          grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.aboutR, 1, 40);
      }
    });

    MenuItem RServe = new MenuItem ("About RServe");
    RServe.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
      public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.textRef.setFill(Color.FIREBRICK);
          fr.md.pack.TextClass.textRef.setText(fr.md.pack.StringClass.aboutText);
          grid.add(fr.md.pack.TextClass.textRef, 1, 40);


      }
    });


    file.getItems().addAll(upload,exit);
    test.getItems().addAll(arima,acf,pacf,hw);
    help.getItems().addAll(arimaH,acfH,pacfH,hwH);
    about.getItems().addAll(thisS, R, RServe);


    menuBar.getMenus().addAll(file,test,help,about);


    root.getChildren().addAll(menuBar,grid);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
}
```

The classes used are just containing the strings to display:

```
package fr.md.pack;

public class StringClass {
    final static String aboutText = "Малко информация за RServe.";
    final static String aboutRtext = "Малко инфо за Р";
    final static String aboutSofttext = "Малко инфо за софта";
    final static String aboutArima = "Малко инфо за ARIMA";
    final static String aboutACF = "Малко инфо за ACF";
    final static String aboutPACF = "Малко инфо за PACF";
    final static String aboutHW = "Малко инфо за Holt Winters";

}
```

Comment: When you do fileChooser.showOpenDialog you lock the execution untill fileChooser is closed. It is usual. WHat is wrong?

Comment: If you think that your second code blocks execution then It seems impossible

Comment: As mentioned above the FileChooser is just fine, the problem is in the acfH. I guess I did not explained why I included it. I included it, just to show that I use the same logic when I write the other ActionEvents. Sorry about it! I will correct it!

Comment: I does block the whole app! I can't anything after choosing it.

Comment: From what you posted it is difficult to guess what is wrong. Indeed could you post some working example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I hope [this tutorial](http://java-buddy.blogspot.com/2012/03/javafx-20-filechooser-open-file-dialog.html) will help you:)

Comment: Thanks. I will have a look, but the fileChooser is not finished yet.Nevertheless I will have a look.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just installed Java 8 and surprise....everything is working just fine. I used till now Java 1.7 update 45 and it was locking my application as soon as I try to use the Action event. With Java 8 it's working but not without some bugs....